# Istio RBAC JWT match user claim resource

Tags: jwt, rbac, istio

I was wondering if it is possible to limit which resources is a user allowed to see based on its `userid`.

For example, suppose I have this endpoint:

`GET /user/{userid}`

Which will give me the information for the given user ID.
I want to limit which users can access that resource, only user with ID `X` should be able to view `/user/X`, user with ID `Y` should get a `401` if tries to do that.

The JWT payload could be something like:

```
{
  "sub": "{userid}",
  "name": "{username}"
}
```

And for this example:

```
{
  "sub": "X",
  "name": "User X"
}
```

Is this possible with Istio?

Comment: Have you looked at Istio [ServiceRoleBinding](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#servicerolebinding)? I think it can be useful also for decision making solutions based on JWT.

Comment: Thanks @mk_sta, I've looked into it, but I haven't seen how to achieve exactly what I want: permit access only to the owner of the resource.

Comment: Do you use mTLS communication inside Istio mesh?

Comment: The approach that I can see as a solution is using roles / groups and add those as claims to your JWT, then verify based on those. Checkout end-user authentication.
Otherwise, you can always match by regex in the VirtualService and abort the requests.

Comment: I finally implemented this in 2 different ways:
- Authorize directly in the application based on the requested resource and claims.
- Use external authorizacion with OPA, which allows me to write complex rules